# How to set image in ui files QT, example for QPushButton?

Tags: qt

I know how to set in a programm, but I want to set it in ui files. When I will generate code from ui, icons will have set.

Comment: what exactly do you mean with seeing an image in the ui file? as a resource?

Comment: In designer form, if you click on push button, menu on the bottom right will appear. Under  the QAbstractButton pane you will have an option to change icon (either from resource or from your local fs)

Answer (score 1):

I have decided this problem.

You need to add in ui files:

```
<item>
 <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_Main_Connect_1">
  <property name="icon">
   <iconset theme=":/icons/icons/idc_connect.ico"/>
  </property>
 </widget>
</item>
```

and in the end ui files:

```
 </widget>
 <resources>
  <include location="icons.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

and create qrc files(for example icons.qrc)

```
<RCC>
 <qresource prefix="icons">
  <file>icons/idc_connect.ico</file>
 </qresource>
</RCC>
```

I am using python, because then need to use

> pyrcc5 icons.qrc -o icons_rc.py

> pyuic5 design.ui -o design.py